# How to use Ubuntu's PHP-doc

Tags: installation, php, documentation

I run

```
 sudo apt-get install php-doc
```

I did not find a man entry, nor "which" entry for the program.
There is no "phpdoc" -program in my PATH altough I have /usr/bin in my PATH which apparently should be the location of the installed program.

**How can you use the program in terminal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `php-doc` package just contains documentation for the core PHP functions, from http://php.org/documentation/ - no programs.

```
firefox /usr/share/doc/php/index.html &
```

...and this is how you use it.

(If you were trying to install phpDocumentor instead, other answers already have instructions.)

Comment: I do not have the file which you open in Firefox. How did you obtain the file?

Comment: Eh, it seems Debian's package uses `/usr/share/doc/php-doc/html/` instead, try that.

Comment: Ubuntu Precise (12.04) also uses this path.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242064/how-to-create-phpdoc-tutorial-extended-pages-to-supplement-commented-code) stackoverflow question.

There is also an overview of how to [run phpdoc on the comandline](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line) as part of a larger [tutorial](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html).

Also, try the [README](http://docs.huihoo.com/api/phpdocumentor/1.3.1/ric_README.html) - you may need to build it from source.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed phpdoc as in phpdoc.org

You just installed some PHP documentation.

This is from the description:
"This package provides the documentation for the PHP scripting language."

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the php5-cli package:

sudo apt-get install php5-cli

Then you can run php from the terminal using:
php filename.php